# Why did inspector ask to move P-trap above floor?

Tags: plumbing

Our contractor installed the Ptrap for our washer drain below the subfloor, basically in the crawl space.

We had everything nicely tucked inside the wall.

[image: wall plumbing]

Then the inspector asked him to move the Ptrap above the subfloor. 
All the pipes and vents would not fit so the contractor had to thicken the wall so there would be space for the Ptrap and the dryer vent.

[image: plumbing and thicker wall]

What would be the reason for this? Is this code?

Comment: In the UK we would  not hide the trap in a wall, so that it can be cleaned out **when** (not if) it gets blocked.

Comment: As an American I must admit that the UK tends to think things through and save customers time and money. Sadly here in the states, people tend to have a throw away replace it mentality.

Comment: There is an opening to the right of the water valves. You'll see hat the black pipe runs vertically up to the white box. The drain line from the washer will be fed into it. If it gets clogged I think we can use that opening to clear the clog.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**All traps must be installed on the same floor as the fixture served with the exception of tubs and showers.**

You can probably find that code bit in the DWV section, not necessarily under washing machines. In any case putting it below the floor would violate the maximum length of the stand pipe code which is 30"

---

**The Need for a P-trap**

If you create a waste pipe for any fixture that needs draining, including a washing machine, and the drain doesn't have a properly installed P-trap, you're creating a dangerous situation. The pool of water in the bottom of the trap effectively seals sewer gases inside the pipes, and if you omit the trap, the gases have a direct route into your house. Besides being laden with harmful organisms that you can inhale, some sewer gases, such as methane, are flammable. If the washer is in an enclosed area, you could actually create a fire hazard by omitting the trap or from improper installation.

Comment: Got it. So my contractor should have known this...

Comment: I wouldn't say he/she did not know but I would like to think that as a plumbing contractor, code for P-traps should not be uncommon to say the least. I know as a general contractor, I knew most all the codes for handicap even when its not commonly used except in commercial building.

Comment: @milesmeow Was the "contractor" a plumber?  If you hire a contractor to do work in your home, and they are not having the work done by skilled trades people, you should expect the work to not be perfect.  Skilled trades people know much more about their trade, than somebody who tries to be a jack of all trades.  When you spend all day every day doing a thing, you learn a lot about how to do that thing.  If you spend all day doing lots of things, you learn a little bit about a lot of things.

Comment: He hired two guys that do framing, electrical and plumbing.

Comment: Yeah, any time you start dealing with Sub's, problems become more common. Anyone doing plumbing work should have known the p-trap has to be accessible.

Comment: Why does the P-trap have to be on the same floor?  Will the P-trap not function correctly if is not on the same floor? Why does the stand pipe have to be 30" or less?

Comment: @milesmeow "He hired two guys that do framing, electrical and plumbing" Did he hire another general? 3 is the magic number for a general to be involved and I can not think that he would hire a sub to do work outside their license and abilities...

Comment: The ptrap will work even if it's on a different floor. I think it's more a question of having it be accessible or it not freezing. Is there something specific under the floor?